# Independency of stochasts and an event

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Define $U_1,U_2,...$ as an infinite sequence of stochasts which are i.i.d. Suppose we have a given $a < b$ and $1 > \mathbb{P}[U_1 > a] > \mathbb{P}[U_1 > b] > 0$. Define the following:
$$I = \min\{n \ | \ n \geq 1, U_n > a\}$$ We would like to show that $U_I$ and $I$ are independent. It is true, and I can prove it. (I proved that $\mathbb{P}[U_I > c, I = k] = \mathbb{P}[U_I > c]\cdot \mathbb{P}[I=k]$ for a $c > a )$. But I can not find an intuitive idea why these two are independent. Can somebody explain me (in words) why these two are independent

Answer (score 1):

If we think of the realizations of the $U_n$ chronologically (first $U_1$, then $U_2$ et cetera) then there will be a first time that we will meet an index $k$ such that $U_k>a$.

I cannot think of any reason why the value taken by this index $k$ will have influence on (the distribution of) this $U_k$.

The $U_i$ that preceed can just be neglected and the distribution involved will be the same as the distribution of $U_1$ under the extra condition that $U_1>a$.

I hope this helps your intuition.